# Why does not promotion engine work correctly in Hybris?

Tags: java, spring, sap-commerce-cloud, promotions

As I have observed, Promotion engine (drools-based) has not worked stably in Hybris. For instance, I have a promotion named free-shipment if your order total is more than $150, you will have free shipment.Whenever I deploy the release of Hybris (v6.4) to production environment, it would not work.
When I redeploy the same promotion, it would work.

This has happened in my local environment without no reason as well. Promotions have not frequently worked unexpectedly till redeploying them.(It is possible to say the reason is because of changing current branch but I never changed it)

Has anybody ever experienced such a situation? What would be the reason?

Answer (score -2):

From what I understand, it works in the local environment, but it doesn't work on the server?

And you're sure there's no restriction?